# Automating the creation of a database in SQL Server hosted in Amazon RDS

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-rds

I have been doing some research with SQL Server hosted in Amazon RDS. I am planning on having an application that requires multi tenancy solution - one database per customer with a core database for login etc.

So Im playing with RDS/SQL Server but there are come problems I need to overcome. Firstly how do automate the creation of a database? I RDS I cannot just restore from a bak file and I want to create database schema from template. Does anybody have any experience with this and if so can you guide me with some tips?

Thanks,

kseudo

Comment: Have you looked at using SMO? (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1826/getting-started-with-sql-server-management-objects-smo/) or alternatively simply using Management Studio and the "Generate Scripts..." task?

Answer (score 1):

Generate Scripts is a good starting point for this but if you truly want to automate the database creation you'll want to convert the script that is output from SQL Server's Generate Script into a template.

A good way to do this would be to create a .NET application or even just a stored procedure that will do a find and replace on the script once you've made it into a template.

1. Create your template customer database with all the objects you want
   in it and then script out the database (all database objects).
2. In C# or in SQL build a dynamic query by including a variable in every object name:

   ```
    CREATE DATABASE CustomerDB_1 ...

    "CREATE DATABASE CustomerDB_{0}" //Formatted String in C#
    'CREATE DATABASE CustomerDB_' + @vchCustomerID //Dynamic SQL
   ```

   If every object name has the customer ID in it and every database has a unique customer ID, then you can simply run the query after replacing the variables with the appropriate values and you're all set.

Comment: Oh and something to consider with Amazon RDS if you don't go with an unlimited DB plan, you can always have 1 master database and have different tables for each customer -- each customer could have it's own schema and you wouldn't have to worry about maximum number of DB restrictions. Not sure if that's applicable for you but just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Chris,

Your initial post has given me some ideas on how to implement a solution to my problem.

I will post again should I have made some progress... thanks again

Comment: Hi @kSeudo I'm looking into a similar setup. We require individual databases for all of our clients, but the creation process takes too long and we'd like to automate it. Did you manage to solve your problem with Chris' suggestion? Thanks in advance.